# Multi-Parameter Matching

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, matching-theory

Given is a pool of $400$ elements that are supposed to be matched pairwise based on the following rules:

- Each element has a parameter $x$, and the matching should be done so that $x_1$ (first element of a pair) plus $x_2$ (second element of a pair) are as big as possible while the sum is globally as equal as possible.
- Each element has a parameter $y$, and the matching should be done so that 
  [$(\frac1{y_1} + \frac1{y_2})^{-1}$](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%)
  is as small as possible while the result is globally as equal as possible.

Out of the $400$ elements, **a set of $280$** is supposed to be created so that the conditions above are met optimally.

Trying all possible combinations would be something like
[$\binom{400}{280}$](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.download?%5Cbinom%7B400%7D%7B280%7D) which is a very large number according to 
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=400%20choose%20280).

I am searching for an algorithm that is capable of calculating the optimal matching of elements in the best runtime possible.